# Issues installing xcode from command line

Tags: xcode

So I'm running the following

```
sudo hdiutil attach ~/Xcode_7.3.dmg

cp -r /Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app /Applications/
```

However if I try to run Xcode, it gives the following error after attempting to verify xcode. "Xcode can't be opened because the identity of the developer cannot be confirmed".  Note that if I try to install the traditional way (double click on dmg -> drag to Applications), I don't have this problem.

For context: We have a whole bunch of teamcity servers that we need to install various versions of xcode for and I would really love to automate it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I ran "man cp" and noticed the following comment.

```
Historic versions of the cp utility had a -r option.  This implementation
supports that option; however, its use is strongly discouraged, as it
does not correctly copy special files, symbolic links, or fifo's.
```

So changing the cp command from -r to -R fixed it.

Rookie mistake by me.